# Checking out a single blob by hash from remote HTTPS repo

Tags: git

Git has two https protocols - dumb and smart.
With the dumb protocol it's trivial to download a single blob without cloning the whole repo.

How can I do the same using the smart HTTPS Git protocol?

Given an https repo URL and a blob hash, how can I download just that blob (doing a short sequence of requests)?

Comment: https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/technical/http-protocol.txt might help? Then again, maybe not.

Answer (score 1):

You're partially correct in that with the dumb HTTP protocol you can download a single blob *if it's a loose object*.  If it's packed, then you have to download the entire pack, or possibly all the packs, to fetch the single object.

As for fetching a single blob using the smart protocol, that's only possible if the server provides partial clone.  Even with that limitation, you'll need to write a manual client that speaks the [smart protocol](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/technical/pack-protocol.txt) to fetch the single blob.  It may also, depending on the server implementation, be necessary to fetch a containing commit and use the `blob:none` and `tree:0` filters at the same time, so be prepared to try both.  Git doesn't provide this functionality natively.